# Search in all Production Orgs at once and Display in one single org

Tags: salesforce2salesforce, production, global-search

I have an urgent requirement, my client has 3 Production orgs due to the versatility of business, sales users search for an account name eg: 'Johns Garage' in one Production org, users should be able to see data from all 3 orgs in one of them where he searched. Is there a Salesforce functionality to make this happen except webservices callouts written in Java?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many ways to do this. At least these two options you could explore:

- **Salesforce to Salesforce** : https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Salesforce_to_Salesforce
- **Salesforce Connect** : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=platform_connect_about.htm&type=0

In my experience, Salesforce Connect sounds great, but is very expensive and must be purchased additionally.

You could also write some code and use the SOAP-API to make some cross-org-callouts not using Java but APEX.

Comment: Thank you Uwe for your prompt response. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use restAPI call for other environment and implement custom search which will be flexible. Salesforce to Salesforce is also a good option without coding.

Comment: Thank you Avijit for your prompt response. restApi I am already using through Java. But facing various other issues implementing custom search.

Comment: Are you using standard rest API.  You can define your own api which will take input as per your control